# Using radon function to find black bar position in white background image

Tags: matlab, projection

I want to use radon projection find horizontal position (x coordinate) of the black bar in white image (first image). However my code returns the result in third image while my expectation is second image. What is the problem, my code is here:

```
clear; clc;
img = rgb2gray(imread('2.png'));
bwimg = ~im2bw(img); 
[R, xp] = radon(bwimg, 0);

[h w] = size(img);    
dw = w / length(xp);
[a ix] = max(R(:,1));
pos = round(w/2 + xp(ix)*dw);
bwimg(:, pos) = 1;
figure; imshow(bwimg);
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `pos = round(w/2 + xp(ix));` (without the `dw`). Also, why not just use `[~, pos] = max(sum(bwimg,1));` instead of doing a radon transform?

Comment: thank you, it works. Could you tell me how can I use radial coordinate xp(ix) directly?  For your question, I want to learn about radon transform.